# Want display user selected image in different ejs file

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying user selected image in my ejs file, but i want the user selected image in different ejs file.

Ejs file

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="PatientEmrController">
        <h1>Upload a file</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form ng-submit="uploadFile()" class="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="title" ng-model="titleText" class="form-control" required>
                <br><br>


<file-field ng-model="uploadThis" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-success':uploadThis}" preview="uploadPreview" name="up" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg">Select file</file-field>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img ng-src="{{uploadPreview}}" ng-if="uploadPreview" class="img-responsive" >   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</html>
```

Js file

```
sample.controller('PatientEmrController',['$scope','$http','$injector',function($scope,$http, $injector){



    //  $injector.invoke(ParentCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});


    // $scope.title = 'project';
    // $scope.image_url = 'images/generic.jpg';
    // $scope.image_num = 14; //image count -> [0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ..., 13.jpg]




$scope.myFunction = function(){
       return "https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
       // return "uploadPreview"
    }

    $scope.uploadFile=function(n){

        if(!$scope.uploadThis){
            alert('Please select a file to upload.')
            return;
        }






        var fd = new FormData();

        //you can also send other fields
        //this will be available as req.body.title
        //NOTE: files must be added AFTER other form data
        fd.append('title', $scope.titleText);

        //nacho relates to what we called the file
        //in the api on sails
        fd.append('nacho', $scope.uploadThis);
        $http.post('/api/burrito', fd, {
            //transformRequest: angular.identity,
            //headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            up:$scope.uploadThis,
            title: $scope.titleText,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(data){
            console.log('upload data',data);
            if(data.result){

                alert('file uploaded. See .tmp/uploads folder.');
            }


        })
        .error(function(err){
            alert('there was an error uploading the file.');
            console.log(err);
        });        
    }


}]);
```

In this js file, i used myFunction,and i bind this function in the ejs file(in which i want to display user selected image, i used this function in ng-src).so here, one image return in that ejs file, because , i write one image url, so google image return , so i want to return user selected image here, how is it possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What I understand is you are trying to download an image from url and display it on another page?

Comment: yes,i am selecting image(choose file), and i am able to display it on one ejs file, but i want to display same image(which user select) in another ejs file.I do not know , how this will happen.

Comment: You are downloading the image which user selects?

Comment: Actually,Files stored at tmp folder folder of my project, and also displayed (in my ejs file), and i want to display it in another ejs file....

Comment: You can simply store the name of the selected image in a variable and give it to <img src="<% selectedImagePath%>" > would this fix your problem?